# How can I view the source IE refers to when it gives JS errors?

Tags: internet-explorer

IE keeps telling me to look on line 1 char 98, but it's for an iframe, so I can't right click and do view source, because nothing pops up. It keeps giving me js errors but I have no freaking idea where to find them. The link it gives is worthless because I can't select it and it's too long to retype, besides it probably has js that will redirect back into the iframe. I'm getting so sick and tired of dealing with IE's crap.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Download IE Developer toolbar. After this, select "View Generated Source". This would show JS code that is actually being executed. This includes JS code injected at runtime.

Download URL : http://www.microsoft.com/downloads/en/details.aspx?FamilyID=95e06cbe-4940-4218-b75d-b8856fced535

Comment: I downloaded that but I don't see any "view generated source" button. I can see the thing the bar at the bottom of the ie, so it's opened. I just see the file, and tools and all the links.

Comment: Like, the problem is it's on facebook, the only place I can test it is IN the facebook iframe, but IE doesn't seem to allow me to debug or view the iframe code at all, though it gives me the errors from the iframe code.

Comment: This is a tutorial that shows how to view generated source : http://ciitronian.com/blog/programming/tutorial-using-ie-developer-tools-as-firebug-in-mozilla-firefox/   OR you can set a breakpoint in console (after installing Dev toolbar). That would work even if source of that iframe is javaScript from facebook.

Answer (score 1):

Press F12 and view the console tab, it should give you more information and you can even debug the code. You should be able to double click an error to go to the line in question.

Comment: it has a pop-up that show the error 'null is null or not an object' I have no idea what it's talking about. It says line 1, char 98. I've tried double-clicking everything in the error pop up box and it doesn't take me to any code. I pressed f12 all over the place and nothing popped up.

Comment: Can you find out where the error is, like which part of the code it's talking about with this null crap?

Comment: I'd check but I'm not allowing that app access to my profile. F12 should open the developer tools window in IE. If not try Tools > Developer Tools to open it.

Comment: I opened it, but it doesn't let me view the source of an iframe. It will stop at <BODY>

Comment: Also it only shows using the pyramid display, however I think the actual source it's referencing is all on line 1, which makes it difficult to find where char 98 is.

Comment: In the developer tools select the script tab and use the drop down on the tool bar to view the different script files that are loaded with the page. Find the one where the first line has at least 98 characters. Good luck! BTW did you check the console tab?

Comment: You can copy the code into a text editor so you can see what line/character you're on. You could also try Firebug in Firefox.